# TCPDF : Set margin between several images get by 'foreach' method

Tags: php, foreach, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF, I'm trying to set row and column to typeset on pdf images get by foreach method.
Here is my code:

```
$imagesValues = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image');
foreach ( $imagesValues as $imageItem ) { 
    foreach ( $imageItem as $imageID ) { 
        $imageURL = wp_get_attachment_url($imageID); // gets photo URL
        $pdf->Image($gallerieURL, $x, $y, $w, $h, 'JPG', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false); 
    } 
}
```

**EDIT**

I have done that :

```
$x = 115;
$y = 35;
$w = 25;
$h = 50;
foreach ( $imagesValues as $imageItem) { 
  foreach ( $imageItem as $imageID) { 
    $imageURL = wp_get_attachment_url($imageID); // gets photo URL
    $x = 115;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 2; ++$i) {
      $pdf->Image( $imageURL, $x, $y, $w, $h, 'JPG', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
      $x += 27; // new column
    }
    $y += 52; // new row
  }   
}
```

But the same images repeat themselves

Comment: You could try to play around with $w and $h along with $fitbox, see here: http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a714c2bee7d6b39d4d6d304540c761352

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that there is several images. How can I set different parameters for each one of them?

Comment: You have defined these variables earlier: `$w, $h` so just redefine them within the loop. It would be easier if you included these in the data source so maybe `$imageValues` could have this information inside of it too which would make it available within the loop iteration? Read about multi-dimensional arrays if what I have said confuses you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I try this right now!

Comment: No problem, if you get stuck i can give you a brief example, let me know.

Comment: Actually I get stuck, if you could give me a example I will be very grateful to you!

Comment: They repeat themselves because that is what you are doing with your for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was suggesting that you change your data source to look like:

```
array (
  0 => array (
    'w'=>320,
    'h'=>240
  ),
  1 => array (
    'w'=>300,
    'h'=>250
  ) 
)
```

But okay, you need simply do a little calculation here:

```
// Assuming that 115 is the width of the row
$x = 0;
// Assuming that 52 is the height of each
$y = 0;
$w = 25;
$h = 50;

// We start on 1 image, there are 4 images in each row
$imageCounter = 1;

foreach ( $imagesValues as $imageItem) { 
  foreach ( $imageItem as $imageID) { 
    // gets photo URL
    $imageURL = wp_get_attachment_url($imageID);
    // Calculate the column and row specifications
    switch ($imageCounter) {
      // First column
      case 1: 
        $x = 0;
        $imageCounter ++;
      break;
      case 2: 
        $x = 27;
        $imageCounter ++;
      break;
      case 3: 
        $x = 54;
        $imageCounter ++;
      break;
      case 4: 
        $x = 81;
        // Reset the image counter back to 1 for the new row
        $imageCounter = 1;
        // New row
        $y += 52;
      break;
    }
    $pdf->Image( $imageURL, $x, $y, $w, $h, 'JPG', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
  }       
}
```

Comment: Whoops, see the update. You just need to increment the counter on the 1st, 2nd and 3rd images of the row.